# React Native fetch throws error when posting multipart/form-data

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

This is how I tried to POST an image as multipart/form-data to server.

```
var photo = { uri: this.state.avatarSource,
              type: 'multipart/form-data', 
              name: 'photo.jpg', }; 
let formdata = new FormData(); 
formdata.append('attachment',photo); 
fetch(url,
        { method: "POST", 
          headers: { 'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data' }, 
          body: formdata 
        }).then((response) => response.json()) 
       .catch((error) => { alert("ERROR " + error) }) 
       .then((responseData) => { alert("Succes "+ responseData) }).done();
```

> But it shows an error : Expected dynamic type string but had type
>   object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After 2 days, trying so many things I made the code working with some modifications.

```
RNFetchBlob.fetch('POST', url, {
  'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
}, [ 
    { name: 'file', filename: 'photo.jpg', type: 'image/png', data: RNFetchBlob.wrap(src) }
  ]) .then((resp) => {
    console.log(resp.text());
  }).catch((err) => {
    console.log(err);
  });
```

Comment: what is src here ?

Comment: @Anuj me also asking the same thing here

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/append) `formData.append(name, value, filename);`

The `value` field in it accepts [`USVString`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/USVString) or [`Blob`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob), since you're passing an `object` to it therefore it throws an error.

You need to convert your `image` to `blob`, append and upload it.

If you've got the `base64` of the image, then you can convert it to a `blob` directly using the `fetch` api

```
fetch(base64URL)
.then(res => res.blob())
.then(blob => console.log(blob))
```

Otherwise you may checkout [RN-fetch-blob](https://github.com/joltup/react-native-fetch-blob#multipartform-data-example-post-form-data-with-file-and-data), their `multipart/ formData` example.

Comment: I have the base64 of the image. But i dont want to use it like that way. because I need to upload video too but not right now. so I have to upload this way only.

Comment: Then you might need to use RN-fetch-blob, and you can upload your video and the image by specifying the fileName as `filename: 'vid.mp4'` , or image as `filename : 'avatar-foo.png'` as this line suggests     `{ name : 'avatar-foo', filename : 'avatar-foo.png', type:'image/foo', data: RNFetchBlob.wrap(path_to_a_file)},` in their docs

Comment: I tried but getting an error "Failed to create form data from path :[object Object], file not exists"

Comment: I found that I had to use `formData.append(…, type: 'multipart/form-data'`) for it to work on Android …

Comment: res.blob() is not a function issue

Answer (score 0):

I slightly modified the solution given by @unknown123. And it worked for me.
Here is the solution.

First, install npm package [rn-fetch-blob](https://www.npmjs.com/package/rn-fetch-blob)

> import RNFetchBlob from 'rn-fetch-blob';
>
> RNFetchBlob.fetch('PUT', url, {'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'},
>   Platform.OS === 'ios' ? RNFetchBlob.wrap(filePath) :
>   `RNFetchBlob-${filePath}`)

**Please note, in my case, I had different file paths for IOS and Android devices. We handle it in different ways using rn-fetch-blob**

Sample filePath variable data for

1. IOS device -

"/Users/Niveditha/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/B41EB910-F22B-4236-8286-E6BA3EA75C70/data/Containers/Data/Application/B88777C6-6B10-4095-AB67-BB11E045C1DE/tmp/react-native-image-crop-picker/img.jpg"

2. Android device -

"**file://**/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.uploadcameraroll/files/Pictures/img.jpg"